# aws-cli: Exporting region env var not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-cli

I am spinning up a `debian:jessie` container.

After performing:

```
pip install awscli
```

I export my credentials:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<myaccesskeyid>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<mysecretkey>
```

but exporting the region does not seem to work

```
root@cae75eebe847:/# export AWS_REGION=eu-west-1
root@cae75eebe847:/# $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```

Any suggestion?

Running `aws configure` interactively did the job but I am trying to script this.

The above is taking place inside a `debian:jessie` container and I am using:

```
$ docker info | grep -i version
WARNING: No swap limit support
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-32-generic
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct environment variable for region is `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html) link for the list of environment variables. You specified `AWS_REGION` (which is incorrect).

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it's not the OP's fault. Amazon's own documentation has the variable wrong in some places. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

Comment: The docs are not wrong. The linked page is for Java SDK. Many AWS SDKs (Go, JavaScript, .NET, Go, Java, Ruby) indeed use AWS_REGION. But the CLI is written with the Python SDK, which is actually the odd ball and uses AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.